# With Terraform, how do I integrate a basic-sku load balancer and basic-sku public ip address with an azurerm_kubernetes_cluster resource?

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure, azure-load-balancer

Provisioning a minimal aks cluster with `azurerm_kubernetes_cluster` with defaults creates a `load_balancer_sku = standard` along with a `load_balancer_profile` block. A LoadBalancer and IP Address is then visible in the resources list at portal.azure.com.

However, setting `load_balancer_sku = basic` creates "nothing" - no mention of it in terraform state (outside of label), no load_balancer_profile block, and no resources are created in portal.azure.com. (I also cannot find any information about how to correctly create an aks cluster that works with basic-sku `azurerm_lb` and basic-sku `azurerm_public_ip`, so links to comprehensive resources are appreciated.)

From the bits and pieces of info I did find, I glued together the following code:

```
# azurerm_kubernetes_cluster
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "k8s" {
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  name                = var.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  node_resource_group = "${local.node_resource_group_name}"
  dns_prefix          = "${local.dns_prefix}"

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  default_node_pool {
    name       = "agentpool"
    vm_size    = "Standard_B2s"
    node_count = 1
  }

  network_profile {
    network_plugin = "kubenet"
    load_balancer_sku = "basic" # ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-overview#pricing-and-sla
  }
}

# azurerm_public_ip
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "k8s_lb_ip" {
  name                = "PublicIPForLB"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s.node_resource_group # NOTE - is this really required? I do not want the IP in the NRG as it will be destroyed if azure updates the node pool!
  allocation_method   = "Static"
}

# azurerm_lb
resource "azurerm_lb" "k8s_lb" {
  name                = "BasicLoadBalancer"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name

  frontend_ip_configuration {
    name                 = "PublicIPAddress"
    public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.k8s_lb_ip.id
  }
}

# azurerm_role_assignment
# ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/static-ip?source=recommendations#create-a-service-using-the-static-ip-address
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "lb_ip_aks_integration" {
  description = "Allows a basic-sku load balancer and basic-sku Public IP integration with an AKS cluster whose load_balancer_sku = basic."
  principal_id                     = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s.kubelet_identity[0].object_id
  role_definition_name             = "Network Contributor"
  scope                            = azurerm_public_ip.k8s_lb_ip.id
  skip_service_principal_aad_check = true
```

The last stanza uses `azurerm_role_assignment`. [This Microsoft Learn article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/static-ip?source=recommendations#create-a-service-using-the-static-ip-address) discusses setting up a standard LB with `azure-cli`. It implies that `azurerm_public_ip.resource_group_name` must be set to the cluster's node resource group name. This is not ideal, so I hope this isn't true. I want the IP address to existing in the resource group name so that it's not destroyed if the auto-managed nrg is. The scope is inferred from that azure-cli command, and the principal_id, I referenced how to use via the [official Terraform example on how to integrate ACR and AKS with the cluster's default `SystemAssigned` identity.](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/container_registry#example-usage-attaching-a-container-registry-to-a-kubernetes-cluster)

In any case, still no luck. If I add the following resource, for example

```
resource "helm_release" "nginx_ingress" {
  name = "nginx-ingress-controller"

  repository = "https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami"
  chart      = "nginx-ingress-controller"

  set {
    name  = "controller.service.externalTrafficPolicy"
    value = "Local"
  }
  set {
      name        = "controller.service.loadBalancerIP"
      value = var.public_ip # azurerm_public_ip.ip_address
   }
}
```

A separate IP address and load balancer are created automatically, unrelated and in addtion to those I specified in the above code.

What am I missing? How do I successfully get the resources I provisioned to coordinate with each other as expected?

Comment: Maybe related https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azure-basic-load-balancer-will-be-retired-on-30-september-2025-upgrade-to-standard-load-balancer/

Comment: Oh, wow! Thanks for that find! To satisfy my own curiosity, I'm hoping to still find out what's wrong in my code logic as it seemed intuitive that the approach that works to integrate ACR with AKS would work here. But given the link you provided, that changes our approach entirely. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below allows for a basic sku LB and IP to be used within an AKS cluster whose load_balancer_sku = basic.

The answer is that the above pattern is obsolete. We used it to establish a consistent public IP address that would never change (for DNS and other purposes), and we attached it to a custom load balancer.

This allowed reconfiguring of the load balancer in a way that would not destroy the entire cluster. The load balancer and custom public ip could exist in its own resource group, and giving the SystemAssigned managed identity access to it via "Contributor" allowed it all to work.

The documentation states that Node Resource Group resources, which are auto-managed by Microsoft, cannot be altered. And now, per Azurerm provider 3.0, this includes the Load Balancer. In other words, the LB is now automatically created and included in the NRG, so it is no longer possible to create a load balancer resource that works with an aks cluster.

However, you can still create a custom Public IP address, which, with the right configuration, can be used with the DNS zones, etc. The pattern now is to create a custom public ip address and assign it to the auto-managed NRG. Then, you are forced to use Microsoft's annotations to implement it, [like this:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/static-ip?source=recommendations#create-a-service-using-the-static-ip-address)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-resource-group: <node resource group name>
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-pip-name: myAKSPublicIP
  name: azure-load-balancer
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
    app: azure-load-balancer
```

From a terraform perspective, here is what it all looks like put together:

```
# 1.create the resource group

# az group create --name myNetworkResourceGroup --location eastus
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "${var.name}-rg"
  location = var.location
}

# 2. create the BASIC cluster
# az aks create --name myAKSCluster --resource-group myNetworkResourceGroup --generate-ssh-keys --tier free --node-count 1
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "k8s" {
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  name                = var.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  node_resource_group = local.node_resource_group_name
  dns_prefix          = local.dns_prefix

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  default_node_pool {
    name       = "agentpool"
    vm_size    = "Standard_B2s"
    node_count = 1
  }

  network_profile {
    network_plugin    = "kubenet"
    load_balancer_sku = "basic" # var.sku naming error # ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-overview#pricing-and-sla
  }
}

# create the custom public ip address and insert it into the NRG
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "k8s_lb_ip" {
  name                = "PublicIPForLB"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s.node_resource_group # NOTE IMPORTANT THIS MUST BE THE NODE RESOURCE GROUP NAME!
  allocation_method   = "Static"
  sku                 = "Basic"
}

# assign the kublet id role to the node resource group id itself (which seems counter intuitive)
# ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/static-ip?source=recommendations#create-a-service-using-the-static-ip-address
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "lb_ip_aks_integration" {
  description          = "Allows a basic-sku load balancer and basic-sku Public IP integration with an AKS cluster whose load_balancer_sku = basic."
  principal_id         = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s.kubelet_identity[0].object_id
  role_definition_name = "Network Contributor"
  scope                            = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s.node_resource_group_id
  skip_service_principal_aad_check = true
}
```

unlike in versions 2.99 and earlier where we explicitely involve the load balancer details, we omit it all together. Instead, because the LB is auto created, we have to use annotations, so in Terraform, like this:

```
resource "kubernetes_manifest" "service" {
  depends_on = [module.aks_cluster]
  manifest = yamldecode(<<YAML
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-resource-group: autolbtest-nrg
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-pip-name: PublicIPForLB
  name: azure-load-balancer
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
    app: azure-load-balancer
YAML
  )
}
```

TODO: use interpolation for the public ip name and the name of the resource group into which the public ip is created

Answer (score 1):

> I integrate a basic-sku load balancer and basic-sku public Ip address with an azurerm_kubernetes_cluster resource using terraform by changing sku.

I agree with [Hackerman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1987838/hackerman) with the insights he provided as the main issue lies in this.

Provisioning an Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) cluster with a basic load balancer and a basic public IP address using Terraform can present challenges, particularly with the ongoing shift from basic to standard SKUs for Azure load balancers.

The Standard Load Balancer represents Azure's broader initiative to streamline its services, emphasizing enhanced availability, scalability, and security features that come with the Standard SKU.

Concerns have been raised about situating the Public IP within the Node Resource Group (NRG), due to the risk of it being destroyed during Azure's node pool updates. It is recommended to house critical resources such as Public IPs in a more stable resource group whenever feasible.

***My Terraform configuration:***

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "teestvk-rg"
  location = "East US"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                = "teestvk-vnet"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/8"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "snet" {
  name                 = "teestvk-snet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.240.0.0/16"]
}

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "k8s" {
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  name                = "teestvk-aks1"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  dns_prefix          = "teestvkaks1"

  default_node_pool {
    name           = "default"
    node_count     = 1
    vm_size        = "Standard_DS2_v2"
    vnet_subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.snet.id
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  network_profile {
    network_plugin     = "azure"
    load_balancer_sku  = "standard"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_container_registry" "acr" {
  name                     = "teestvkacr${random_string.acr_suffix.result}"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  sku                      = "Basic"
  admin_enabled            = false
}

resource "random_string" "acr_suffix" {
  length  = 6
  special = false
  upper   = false
  numeric  = true
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "acr_pull" {
  scope                = azurerm_container_registry.acr.id
  role_definition_name = "AcrPull"
  principal_id         = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s.kubelet_identity[0].object_id
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "k8s_lb_ip" {
  name                = "teestvk-publicip"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  allocation_method   = "Static"
  sku                 = "Standard"
}

resource "azurerm_lb" "k8s_lb" {
  name                = "teestvk-lb"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  sku                 = "Standard"

  frontend_ip_configuration {
    name                 = "PublicIPAddress"
    public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.k8s_lb_ip.id
  }
}
```

**Deployment succeeded:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to test that. I copied and pasted your code verbatim, but it seems to have the same issues as my code. I see the custom teestvk-rg, -lb, and public ip, etc like in your screen shots, but in the auto-generated MC_ node resource group, I also see a different load balancer named 'kubernetes' and a public ip named 'kubernetes-<random>' These two are associated with each other. When I deploy an application with Helm or set Service type LoadBalancer in manifests, it always uses the LB and IP from the NRG, not the custom. The customs are ignored. (cont..)

Comment: ... cont.. This link discusses permissions that the AKS cluster SystemAssigned or other identity needs to interact with other custom resources. Do you not need to use azurerm_role_assignment to allow the kubelet identity to interact with resources outside of the NRG? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-managed-identity

Comment: The behavior observed is inherent to AKS's architecture, which autonomously generates and utilizes its load balancer and public IP for services classified as LoadBalancer, emphasizing simplicity and scalability. Custom load balancers and IPs defined in Terraform are not inherently employed by AKS for its services. Although azurerm_role_assignment is essential for permissions, such as accessing ACR, it does not influence AKS's approach to managing network resources, including the allocation of load balancers and public IPs for services.@user658182